# Difference between String and string C#

Tags: c#, string, difference

Sorry about this dumb question, but i´ve recently found out that you can declare a String or string variable at C#. I would like to know the difference between them, which one is used at specific situations, etc. Thanks for the help and for your time.

Comment: string is like an alias for String.

Comment: You could've considered googling for such a question and would've got about a million answers. Also, learning basics in .Net would help.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference `String` is the Class name and `string` is the alias.

The generaly rule of thumb that I have followed is that if you declare a variable use the alias.

```
string foo = "bar";
```

If you call a method, use the class name

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty("");
```

It is exactly the same for the following"

- Boolean and bool
- Int32 and int
- Double and double

etc